# What's the meaning of "sign the slip"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I suppose she thought she didn’t have to sign the slip because she was so famous, but I made her do it.

What's the meaning of "sign the slip"?

Comment: Have you looked in the dictionary? “Slip” is a small piece of paper, often used to record items of administrative information like the details of who has been allowed to enter, who has left an item in a cloakroom or who has left dry cleaning. (See entry 3 of 5 here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slip). I might add that ‘slips’ are rarely seen nowadays as technology usually fulfills this role.

Comment: But if "she gave him the slip," it might mean she evaded him... or gave him a piece of paper. Strange things that context does.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik. ...or perhaps she gave him an item of her underwear. But we digress because 1: the question is not about giving anyone anything, 2: you can’t sign a verb and 3: making someone famous sign a petticoat would be simply outrageous!

Comment: "Slip" also is used to refer to credit card receipts, which in the US still usually have a line for the card holder to sign. Most stores won't require signing for small amounts though.

Comment: Sorry I slipped up on that... one mistake, and it's a slippery slope downhill.